# Best method for scripting % Processor Time

Tags: c#, powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0, powershell-4.0

I'm trying to use PowerShell to get the results of the % Processor Time performance counter, and I came across this article from 2006:

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/262938

While I'm aware that I can use Add-Type to compile pdh.dll into PowerShell to use, it seems like a great inconvenience when easier methods through cmdlets and .NET Classes exist.  Why would I want to use the Performance Data Helper to get the results of % Processor Time instead of using the Get-Counter cmdlet in PowerShell, or calling System.Diagnostics.PerformanceCounter in .NET?

Comment: `Applies to: Microsoft Win32 Application Programming Interface` where it's the only method.

Comment: @wOxxOm: Thanks .  So, if I'm inferring correctly, there's no need to utilize it a script (like with PowerShell), and it would really only be used for an application that needed to entrench itself as close to the heart and soul of the Windows Operating System as possible?

Comment: Well yes, that's why C/C++ and other languages with direct access to the low-level OS API and hardware exist.